# How to Set programmatically Recurring Profile options to Products

Tags: magento, virtual, recurring-billing, recurring

I am working on virtual products type in magento.i want to set following properties to product progrmmatically.

```
[recurring_profile] => Array
         (
             [start_date_is_editable] => 
             [schedule_description] => 
             [suspension_threshold] => 
             [bill_failed_later] => 
             [period_unit] => 
             [period_frequency] => 
             [period_max_cycles] => 
         )
```

I had searched but no success and i had tried some solutions then also no success.please help me to achive this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid);
    $productname = $_product->getName();
    $_product->setIsRecurring('1');
    $_product->setRecurringProfile(array(
        'start_date_is_editable' => 0,
        'schedule_description' => $productname,
        'suspension_threshold' => 1,
        'bill_failed_later' => 1,
        'period_unit' => day,
        'period_frequency' => 12,
        'period_max_cycles' => 1
    ));
```